# Accidently removed admin/sudo rights

Tags: password, sudo, administrator, user-management

I removed admin rights for the original admin account, in order to set up a new account with clear history. (Not 100% that was needed, I am still getting to grips with linux / Ubuntu 12.04 and I read somewhere that its not wise to use original account day to day, which I initially did.)

However, I didn't activate the password for the new account before applying changes.

Here's what I did:

1. set up new account (no password)
2. Added admin Rights
3. Removed admin right from original
4. No admin access

It now seems as though I have no sudo /admin access. Since I need the 'unset' password of the inactive account, which is the only one with admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

sudo passwd

It will ask you ur username 
Enter username of account u want to make root

It will ask you password

Enter password

And probably that should do the job

Comment: This seems to only be changing the user I am logged in as.  Is there away to activate the the inactive admin account?

Comment: Y don't you enter username of inactive admin account n try it

Comment: @Tejas ...as in `sudo passwd [user]`, right?

Comment: No jus sudo passwd It will prompt u to enter your username there